# Where I can find the pieces needed in a set?

Tags: sets

I own this set, LEGO® Kingdoms King's Castle 7946.

[image]

One day I let my wife's best friend's kids play with it.

(Not the best idea in the world but they had a blast!)

Needless to say, the castle ended up being torn to pieces pretty much.

It has sat in a box for a few months now and I really want to dig it back up for a rebuild.

**The problem I have now is I don't know every piece I need.**

I'm sure some of the pieces have been lost but I have a massive box of extra pieces. Is there a website anywhere that contains the piece count of a set and what pieces are included in the set?

Any ideas on what I can do? or do I have to try my best to rebuild it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't physically have the instructions, you can look up the set ID on [LEGO's Customer Services](http://service.lego.com/en-gb/buildinginstructions) page dedicated to providing building instructions.

The inventory list is usually found right after the final building step. [For #7946 the parts list can be found on pages 74-75.](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4597903.pdf#page=74)

If for whatever reason you cannot access the instructions from the LEGO site, perhaps the file has been removed or you're unable to view PDF files you can still find a part list on sites like [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7946-1) and [Brickset](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=7946-1) (see parts tab).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, I've been wanting to rebuild this one for a while now to place it on my desk. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget Peeron.  You can lookup the parts in your sets, and the site will keep an inventory of the parts you have.

[The parts for set 7946-1 on www.peeron.com](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/7946-1)